# KeyError: 'The optimizer cannot recognize variable dense_1/kernel:0. for pretrained keras model VGG19

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, pre-trained-model

I'm using the following code to load an imagenet pre-trained VGG19 model and fit to my custom dataset.

> 

```
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19


optim = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(momentum=0.9)
vgg19 = VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
vgg19.trainable = False
# x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model_vgg19_pt.output)
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(vgg19.output)
output = keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model_vgg19_pt = keras.models.Model(inputs=[vgg19.input], outputs=[output])
model_vgg19_pt.compile(optimizer=optim,
                       loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)
model_vgg19_pt.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=20,
                             epochs=50, callbacks=[callback]
                             )
```

on model.fit() line, I get the following error

> KeyError: 'The optimizer cannot recognize variable dense_1/kernel:0. This usually means you are trying to call the optimizer to update different parts of the model separately. Please call `optimizer.build(variables)` with the full list of trainable variables before the training loop or use legacy optimizer `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.{self.**class**.**name**}.'

**What does it mean and how can I fix it?**

I get the same errors for

```
keras.applications.inception_v3
```

too, when using the same implementation method.

Additionally, this was working with jupyter notebook file on tensorflow cpu, but when running on a remote machine with tensorflow-gpu installed, I'm getting these errors.

**This works fine with optimizer SGD, but not with RMSprop.** why?

**Additional**
Using this:

```
model_vgg19_pt.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(momentum=0.9),
                           loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

instead as used above works. **But can somebody explain why**....

Comment: Are you running this on Python 3.11? I am getting this error too since upgrading...

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve this and would you know how to solve it for the Adam optimiser? Thanks

Comment: please check the implementation below *Additional* in the question itself, thats the only way it worked for me. I think defining the optimizer in a variable didn't work, but it works as long as I initialize *optimizer* parameter in compile()

Comment: Yes I faced the same issue, and the error goes away by not defining the optimizer as a variable. This was not an issue two months ago, when I ran the SAME code. Very strange.

Answer (score 8):

Use a legacy optimizer

```
 tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
```

Answer (score 2):

When I upgraded from Python 3.9.5 to 3.10.9 with tensorflow==2.11.0,

I got the similar error for Keras Sequential model

```
KeyError: 'The optimizer cannot recognize variable dense_24/kernel:0. This usually means you are trying to call the optimizer to update different parts of the model separately. Please call `optimizer.build(variables)` with the full list of trainable variables before the training loop or use legacy optimizer `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.{self.__class__.__name__}.'
```

Renamed the library to legacy optimizer

from

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import SGD
```

It worked. #niran comment is correct

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Tensorflow GPU have you installed? TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Please check the link to [install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) TensorFlow by following all the Hardware/Software requirements for the GPU support.

The [LearningRateScheduler](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LearningRateScheduler) arguments in callback is not defined which you are passing while  model compilation.

I was able to train the model after removing the callback from model.fit(). (Attaching the [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/c2d63d133ce7a7bf0dfbd66dc28c9ca8/74684240.ipynb) here for your reference)

Comment: I couldn't share the full code, but thanks for pointing it, should've removed the part for easier reproducibility.